# Blender Emission Without Blowing Out Texture (Eevee)

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, emission

So, I want to add emission to an object without blowing out the texture underneath it. Here's my material setup so far: [image]

What would I add (and where) to make add the emission? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the usual `Light Path/Is Camera Ray` node would work for you. Basically, showing only the original non-emission color to the Camera and using Emission node for everything else. This allows you to increase the Emission Strength without affecting the color reaching the camera.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'll try this soon and see if it works.